# Finding $\lim_{x\to 1}\left(2-x\right)^{\tan\frac{\pi x}{2}}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Find the following limit $$L=\lim_{x\to 1}\left(2-x\right)^{\tan\frac{\pi x}{2}}.$$ Without L'Hopital's rule!

My try: $$L=\lim_{x\to1} e^{\ln \left[(2-x)^{\tan\frac{\pi x}{2}}\right]}=\lim_{x\to 1} e^{\tan\frac{\pi x}{2}\ln(2-x)}$$ Now we want to find $$\lim_{x\to1} \tan\frac{\pi x}{2}\ln(2-x)=\ln1\lim_{x\to1}\tan \dfrac{\pi x}{2}$$ I am stuck here.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid l'Hopital's rule?

Comment: Hint: Let $x$ be $1-t$ so you have $L=(1+t)^{1/\tan(\pi t/2)}$, and $\log(L)=t/\tan(\pi t/2)+o(1)$.

Comment: Consider $\tan\theta \approx \theta$ or $\cot\theta \approx \frac{1}{\theta}$ and that $\ln(x+1) \approx x$ These limits can be easily proven by fundamental trig functions.

Comment: Please try to have title lines that do not consist entirely of mathjax/latex. It breaks some navigational shortcuts.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to1}\log (2-x)\tan \dfrac{\pi x}{2} $$
Let $t=1-x$, as $x\to 1$, $t\to 0$ and your limit becomes:
$$\lim_{t\to 0} \log(1+t)\tan \left(\frac{\pi}2(1-t)\right)=\lim_{t\to0}\log(1+t)\cot (\pi t/2)$$
Now, recall that $\log(1+t)\sim t$ and $\cot (\pi t/2)\sim 2/(\pi t)$:
$$\log(1+t)\cot (\pi t/2)\to \frac2{\pi}\ \quad \text{as}\quad t\to 0$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\eqalign{
  & L = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1} {\left( {2 - x} \right)^{\tan \left( {\frac{{\pi x}}{2}} \right)}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1} {\left( {1 + \left( {1 - x} \right)} \right)^{\frac{1}{{1 - x}}\tan \left( {\frac{{\pi x}}{2}} \right)\left( {1 - x} \right)}} = {e^{\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1} \tan \left( {\frac{{\pi x}}{2}} \right)\left( {1 - x} \right)}}  \cr 
  & {\text{And}}:\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1} \tan \left( {\frac{{\pi x}}{2}} \right)\left( {1 - x} \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1} \cot \left( {\frac{\pi }{2} - \frac{{\pi x}}{2}} \right)\left( {1 - x} \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1} \cot \left( {\frac{\pi }{2}\left( {1 - x} \right)} \right)\left( {1 - x} \right)  \cr 
  &  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{{\frac{\pi }{2}\left( {1 - x} \right)}}{{\tan \left( {\frac{\pi }{2}\left( {1 - x} \right)} \right)}}\frac{2}{\pi } = \frac{2}{\pi } \Rightarrow L = {e^{\frac{2}{\pi }}} \cr} $$